# ggplot barplot order xlabel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a barplot that is not stackable and so far I was able to go quite far.

Since I have found out that ggplot plots the data.frame as is, without ordering I have ordered my data.frame before feeding it to ggplot. Where I ordered it based on word occurences

```
Both<-Both[order(Both$occurence,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

The structure looks like now as

```
 str(Both)
'data.frame':   82 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ word     : Factor w/ 6382 levels "a","abcc","abda",..: 1595 1994 
 $ occurence: int  4171 3004 2145 1821 1798 1745 1614 1539 1531 1349 ...
 $ sentiment: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

**Variable**

```
> Both
           word occurence sentiment
**19**            i      4171         0
**12**            m      3004         0
**34**         true      2145         0
**36**      kubelet      1821         1
**18**       normal      1798         1
```

**Plot**

```
ggplot(data=Both,aes(x=word,y=occurence,factor(sentiment),fill=factor(sentiment)))+
coord_flip()+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity")
## remove identity to make them stackable. one after the other
```

but it looks like that ggplot orders my xlabel based on the alphabetical order of the words in other terms the number that is visible in my Both structure and I highlight with ** **.

Why my ordering is not enough? Why ggplot still plots the labels alphabetically?

Comment: that highly upvoted absolute duplicate is hit #1 on google for `ggplot2 order barplot`

Comment: they discuss on factor ordering which based on my understanding is not similar to the data.frame. I am still new to R But I searched for those solutions and I could not apply any of these suggestions I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-order the factor levels from your word column. The order of the levels of that factor will be used to order the x axis.

Use the function `factor` for example.

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(word = as.factor(c('a','b','c')),
          cnt = c(10,20,15))

ggplot(df, aes(x = word, y = cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

df$word <- factor(df$word, levels = c('b','c','a'))

ggplot(df, aes(x = word, y = cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```